# How to keep drawing on canvas when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm wanting to implement canvas as background for my website so users can use their cursors to paint on the webpage like this codepen: https://codepen.io/cocotx/pen/PoGRdxQ?editors=1010
(this is an example code from [http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~clwen/test/canvas-paint-tutorial/](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/%7Eclwen/test/canvas-paint-tutorial/))

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas, context;

  // Initialization sequence.
  function init () {
    // Find the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvas.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Attach the mousemove event handler.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
  }

  // The mousemove event handler.
  var started = false;
  function ev_mousemove (ev) {
    var x, y;

    // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
      x = ev.layerX;
      y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
      x = ev.offsetX;
      y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    // The event handler works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
    // movements. We start drawing a path made up of lines.
    if (!started) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x, y);
      started = true;
    } else {
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      context.stroke();
    }
  }

  init();
}, false); }
```

The problem is that the cursor stops painting when I scroll until I move my mouse again. Any idea on how to keep cursor painting even when I scroll?

Thanks in advance! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the last mouse event and fire a new *fake* one in the scroll event.

Luckily, the [MouseEvent constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) accepts an *mouseEventInit* object on which we can set the `clientX` and `clientY` values of our new event, so we just need to store these values from the previous event and dispatch it in the `scroll` event.

Now, I couldn't help but rewrite almost everything from your code.
It had a lot of checks for old browsers (like very old ones which should never face the web again anyway), you may want to add it again if you wish.
It wasn't clearing the context, meaning that every time it drew a new line, it also did draw again the previous lines over themselves, leading in fatter lines, with a lot of noise at the beginning, and smoother lines at the end.
This could be fixed in many ways, the less intrusive one was to just clear the context at each frame.
To get the relative mouse position, it now uses the clientX and clientY properties of the event.

And the rest of the changes is commented in the snippet.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let last_event; // we will store our mouseevents here
  
  // we now listen to the mousemove event on the document,
  // not only on the canvas
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', fireLastMouseEvent, { capture: true } );
  // to get the initial position of the cursor
  // even if the mouse never moves
  // we listen to a single mouseenter event on the document's root element
  // unfortunately this seems to not work in Chrome
  document.documentElement.addEventListener( "mouseenter", ev_mousemove, { once: true } );

  // called in scroll event
  function fireLastMouseEvent() {
    if( last_event ) {
      // fire a new event on the document using the same clientX and clientY values
      document.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( "mousemove", last_event ) );
    }
  }
  
  // mousemove event handler.
  function ev_mousemove (ev) {
    const previous_evt = last_event || {};
    const was_offscreen = previous_evt.offscreen;
    
    // only for "true" mouse event
    if( ev.isTrusted ) {
      // store the clientX and clientY props in an object
      const { clientX, clientY } = ev;
      last_event = { clientX, clientY };
    }
    
    // get the relative x and y positions from the mouse event
    const point = getRelativePointFromEvent( ev, canvas );
    
    // check if we are out of the canvas viewPort
    if( point.x < 0 || point.y < 0 || point.x > canvas.width || point.y > canvas.height ) {
      // remember we were
      last_event.offscreen = true;
      // if we were already, don't draw
      if( was_offscreen ) { return; }
    }
    // we come from out-of-screen to in-screen
    else if( was_offscreen ) { 
      // move to the previous point recorded as out-of-screen
      const previous_point = getRelativePointFromEvent( previous_evt, canvas );
      context.moveTo( previous_point.x, previous_point.y );
    }
    
    // add the new point to the context's sub-path definition
    context.lineTo( point.x, point.y );

    // clear the previous drawings
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    // draw everything again
    context.stroke();

  }

  function getRelativePointFromEvent( ev, elem ) {
    // first find the bounding rect of the element
    const bbox = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    // subtract the bounding rect from the client coords
    const x = ev.clientX - bbox.left;
    const y = ev.clientY - bbox.top;

    return { x, y };
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#imageView { border: 1px solid #000; }
canvas {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="imageView" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kaiido, this is perfect, thank you so much! and thanks for your detailed explanation! But what should I change from your code to make sure the cursor would also paint if user starts scrolling straight away without moving their mouse?

Comment: or is it not possible for the browser to get mouse position until user moves it?

Comment: @CocoYuan I think you *should* be able to listen to the `mouseenter` event, which I think *should* fire on the documentElement at page load. It does so in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome, where we apparently are out of luck because in this browser they don't even see the documentElement has being `:hover` until the mouse moves.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, this is great working code but I'm running into problems with my site performance because of the canvas. I'm using this canvas as the background of my one page website which is pretty long, and I've noticed that the drawing becomes slow and laggy after being on the site for a while. So I was wondering if we can do something like this: https://donotdrawapenis.com/ (if you keep drawing you can see it's only drawing a fixed length of line) because maybe this will help with its performance? Thank you! I think I will open another question for it too.

Comment: You could add simple checks to avoid drawing when the mouse is outside the canvas yes, I'll edit tomorrow if I have the time.

Comment: @CocoYuan Sorry it took me so long! Got trapped in many rushes at that time and I forgot about it since then... I now added the checks I was talking about, let me know if it fixed your issue.